# sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (psycopg2.OperationalError) could not translate host name dpg-cnifv15jm4es738nb7fg-a to address:Name/service nt knwn

Tags: postgresql, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy, render

So basically, I'm trying to connect to a PostgreSQL database on Render with my website. The problem I'm encountering is that it works locally, but during deployment, I get this error: "could not translate hostname 'hostname' to address: Name or service not known." I've double-checked everything, and the data seems correct, but I can't find a solution to this problem. Also i get this (Background on this error at: https://sqlalche.me/e/20/e3q8) but I read the docs and nothing seems to help. Here is the code:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, redirect, url_for, flash,request,jsonify,session,get_flashed_messages
from flask_login import UserMixin, LoginManager
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from flask_wtf import FlaskForm
from wtforms import SelectMultipleField, SubmitField
from wtforms.validators import DataRequired,Email
from wtforms import TextAreaField,StringField
from wtforms.validators import ValidationError
from flask_migrate import Migrate
from dotenv import load_dotenv
import os
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker
from sqlalchemy import create_engine, Column, String, Integer, DateTime


engine = create_engine(f'postgresql://web_dev_krgj_user:pass@dpg-cnnkci7sc6pc7399qa6g-a.oregon-postgres.render.com/web_dev_krgj')
Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)



app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = postgresql://web_dev_krgj_user:pass@dpg-cnnkci7sc6pc7399qa6g-a.oregon-postgres.render.com/web_dev_krgj

app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = "secretkey"
db = SQLAlchemy(app)
login_manager = LoginManager(app)


@login_manager.user_loader
def load_user(user_id):
    return Users.query.get_or_404(user_id)


class Users(db.Model, UserMixin):
    __tablename__ = "website_basic"
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    .
    .
    .
    .


with app.app_context():
    db.create_all()

.
.
.
.
.

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Comment: If this *"could not translate hostname 'hostname' to address: Name or service not known."* is the actual unedited  message then the issue is then `EXTERNAL DATABASE URL` has the `hostname` value set to `'hostname'` instead of the actual hostname. If the error message has been edited then whatever value you are using for hostname is not correct for the Postgres instance you are trying to reach.

Comment: 1) You seem to have exposed your password unless that was edited to something not real. If it is the real password I would change it immediately 2) Add information to your question text, not in comments. 3) Has the error message been edited and if so what was the actual error message? 4) I missed this before, what is value of `os.environ.get("SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI")`? And while do you have two URI's?

Comment: Okay. I now edited the message and the code. So i provided the DATABASE_URI with external database url from my database in render. Also I pasted the error message so now it is not edited at all. If you want me to provide additional information I will. Also for the second uri(one with the engine create) is there because I read in the docs that it needs to be provided(I'm not sure if it's correct).

Comment: 1) I am not seeing the changed error message. 2) The docs [Initialize extension 3.1](https://flask-sqlalchemy.palletsprojects.com/en/3.1.x/quickstart/#configure-the-extension) shows only one connection. This is for Flask-SQLAlchemy 3.1.

Comment: This is the error message. sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (psycopg2.OperationalError) could not translate host name dpg-cnifv15jm4es738nb7fg-a to address:Name/service nt knwn

Comment: 1) Add the correct text to the question text. The point is to not make it necessary for folks to read through the comments to get relevant information. 2) This `dpg-cnifv15jm4es738nb7fg-a` != `dpg-cnnkci7sc6pc7399qa6g-a.oregon-postgres.render.com`. I'm betting you are still fetching an erroneous URI from somewhere. Further bet it is here `engine = create_engine()`. Again that seems to be an unnecessary step.

Comment: I will add the text yes but I don’t understand one thing. When i go to my database info then my hostname is dpg-cnifv15jm4es738nb7fg-a but when I go to the external url it gives me link with this name dpg-cnnkci7sc6pc7399qa6g-a.oregon-postgres.render.com. Is it possible then that this is making the problem?

Comment: If you are connecting from outside render.com then I'm going to say yes. I don't use Render, but just in general this `dpg-cnifv15jm4es738nb7fg-a` is not a resolvable host name on the internet, while `dpg-cnnkci7sc6pc7399qa6g-a.oregon-postgres.render.com` is, assuming it the correct one.

Comment: Thanks it worked that was the problem.