OperationalError: could not translate host name to address: Name or service not known with SQLAlchemy and PostgreSQL on render.com
I'm using SQLAlchemy with a PostgreSQL database, and I'm encountering an OperationalError when trying to connect to the database.
The error message is: sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (psycopg2.OperationalError) could not translate host name "dpg-coho1hgl5elc73cr6oj0-a" to address: Name or service not known
Background on this error at
error
I tried connecting to a PostgreSQL database using SQLAlchemy with psycopg2 as the DBAPI, following the documentation's format. I expected to successfully connect to the database. However, I encountered an OperationalError with the message "could not translate host name 'dpg-coho1hgl5elc73cr6oj0-a' to address: Name or service not known".
SQLAlchemy 2.0 Documentation -postgresql 

A name like "dpg-coho1hgl5elc73cr6oj0-a" is only valid on a local network (probably within your private network on render.com). If you want to connect from outside the network you must use the external address that render provides.

This question would be clearer if you've provided additional context on where do you host your PostgreSQL instance (like render.com, indeed) and where from do you connect to it. Possibly related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/78143015/8682376.
